# Hadoop streaming example failed Type mismatch in key from map

Tags: types, hadoop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hadoop-streaming example failed to run - Type mismatch in key from map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576985/hadoop-streaming-example-failed-to-run-type-mismatch-in-key-from-map)

When I ran Hadoop streaming example, it failed with Type mismatch in key from map

Hadoop version 0.21.0
input file content:

adfad

adfasdflkjlj

Command line: $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
    -reducer /bin/wc

Error I got:

java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Please advise. What did I do wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, didn't realize this is Streaming.  You need to customize how your output is split into Key/Value pairs.  The documentation is here: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/streaming.html#Customizing+How+Lines+are+Split+into+Key%2FValue+Pairs

<del>The error message gives you all that you need to know.  Your mapper is defined as outputting LongWritable keys: `Mapper`, and your Reducer expects Text: `Reducer.`

You need to redefine one or the other of them.</del>

Comment: Nice to know, that custom inputs can be specified. Thought it was always, the key and the value separated by a tab.

Comment: Right. Specifically, for the OP's question, you'd want to do something like the example they give: "If a line has less than four "."s, then the whole line will be the key and the value will be an empty Text object (like the one created by new Text(""))."

Comment: The idea being that wc expects just lines of text as input- it doesn't operate on key/value pairs.

Comment: I didn't get the point. Even I changed the input file to be key value pair. Such as "aa bb". It didn't work either. The error was"Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
" Where is the LongWritable at all? What did I miss?

Comment: Looking at this again, it looks like you ought to be running wc as the Mapper, not the Reducer.  What is your expected input/output here?  Are you trying to simulate Word Count?  If so, you need to run /bin/cat as your mapper.

Comment: What should be the input to IdentityMapper? My input file "aa bb" doesn't see to work with the command line in my original question. Something is missing. I was hoping to use this example as a start and evolve to sort the input but this doesn't work.

Comment: IdentityMapper passes along the input given to it.  In your case, an input line is probably the number of the file, and the value is the file name (remember, your 'input' is a directory, not a file). If you make /bin/cat your mapper, you are mapping a file list into the concatenated content of those files (which you can then wc).  You don't want to pass the file names along to wc, do you?

Comment: Yes /bin/cat as mapper definitely works. I suspect Hadoop's example is an error. As it simply doesn't work. Replacing the the mapping with /usr/cat will work. It wasn't clear what's the expected input file in Hadoop's example.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in the release versions of Hadoop. It has been fixed in the code, but has to be released. Alternate solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576985/hadoop-streaming-example-failed-to-run-type-mismatch-in-key-from-map).