# hadoop-streaming example failed to run - Type mismatch in key from map

Tags: streaming, hadoop

```
I was running  $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -D stream.map.output.field.separator=. \
    -D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=4 \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
    -reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer 
What hould be the input file when IdentityMapper is the mapper?
```

I was hoping to see it can sort on certain selected keys and not the entire keys.  My input file is simple 
"aa bb". 
"cc dd"
Not sure what did I miss? I always get this error
    java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:371)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug and here is the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1888). The bug has been identified in Hadoop 0.21.0, but I don't think it's in any of the Hadoop release version. If you are really interested to fix this, you can

- download the source code for Hadoop (for the release you are working)
- download the patch from JIRA and apply it
- build and test Hadoop

Here are the [instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute) on how to apply a patch.

Or instead of using an IdentityMapper and the IdentityReducder, use a python/perl scripts which will read the k/v pairs from STDIN and then write the same k/v pairs to the STDOUT without any processing. It's like creating your own IdentityMapper and the IdentityReducder not using Java.

Comment: Why cat only for IdentityReducer and not for the IdentityMapper?

Comment: `cat` should work well for both.. Thanks for the suggestion.  It is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I was trying my hands on Hadoop with my own example, but got the same error. I used KeyValueTextInputFormat  to resolve the issue. You can have a look at following blog for the same.

http://sanketraut.blogspot.in/2012/06/hadoop-example-setting-up-hadoop-on.html

Hope it helps you.

Peace.
Sanket Raut

Comment: The question was specifically for hadoop-streaming .